# Могу ли я открывать с одной JSP страницы другие не используя для этого методы в контроллере?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

Такой вопрос: Чтобы открыть JSP  страницу обязательно для нее должен быть метод в контроллере? Тоесть для каждой страницы должен существовать свой метод? Объясню что не понятно.
Есть `index.jsp` в которой есть такая строка кода: `<a href="second.jsp">Item2</a>` " Это значит, что на первой странице, есть ссылка, при нажатии на которую я ожидаю открытия второй страницы. Причем вторая страница содержит просто `HTML` код без всяких вставок и параметров. Я даже не  JSP а HTML расширение пробовал. Вобщем вот эта страница:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<div style="text-align: center;">
    Какой-то текст
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

И она не открывается. Я вижу ссылку `http://localhost:4000/api/web/second.jsp` и ошибку

```
HTTP Status 404 - /api/web/second.jsp
```

Но если я делаю это так:
1. Создаю метод в контроллере:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/api/web/second", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String openSecond() {
        return "second";
    }
```

2. В `index.jsp` прописываю вместо `second.jsp` просто `second`:

> `<a href="second">second</a>`

То все работает отлично. Вот и вопрос, могу ли я открывать с одно JSP страницы другие не используя для этого методы в контроллере?

Comment: тут вопрос не открытие другого jps из первого я "Как открыть простой html файл без контроллера"

думаю можно сделать с помошью template, только будет проблема в роутинге.  Вы можете ссылку оформить под какой то формат? К примеру /htmlka/second /htmlka/third? тогда это можно сделать с одним контроллером

Comment: да, это у меня меню будет.Тоесть Полюбому  1 страница == 1 метод контроллера?

Comment: 1 структура страницы = 1 метод контроллера (все страницы схожы)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну одним из вариантов (не самым лучшим, конечно) будет сделать меппинг каталога со статическими ресурсами. В таком случае, правда лучше сразу html, а не jsp страницу делать.

Например, в конфиг спринга добавить:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/static/**" location="/static/" />
```

Если ничего не путаю, то каталог должен быть одного уровня с `WEB-INF`, т.е. что-то вроде:

```
src/
  ...
web/
  resources/
    second.html
  WEB-INF/
    ...
```

Comment: А почему не самый лучший? если у меня например есть 5 страниц статических, то наоборот же логичнее так сделать, чем писать контроллер методы и тд. Или нет? можете объяснить пожалуйста, я только начал все это изучать. Именно веб

Comment: Ну, как правило, в ресурсы помещают всякие шрифты, картинки и пр.
Если html действительно статичный, то можете и так сделать. Но если вдруг понадобится на него добавить хоть 1 динамический элемент (например добавить имя пользователя/загрузить данные с базы и т.д.), то придется переделывать.

В целом же, раз уж взялись за MVC, то лучше следовать его стандартам реализации и не изобретать велосипедов =)

Comment: "следовать его стандартам реализации и не изобретать велосипедов " писать методы или делать статику? не совсем понял))) Просто мне не сложно это делать, но хочеться правильно. Я андроид разрабочик, и глядя на проекты некоторые, тошнит. не хочу чтобы когото стошнило от моего спринга)

Comment: Делать метод =) Конечно, тут нельзя дать однозначный ответ, т.к. все зависит от контекста. Но обычно как минимум в 90% необходимо возвращать не просто статические страницы, а все же некоторый динамически формируемый контент, и использование пары лишних методов не является избыточным плюс добавляет некоторые удобства в плане того же роутинга. Если это не так, и у Вас в основном статичный сайт с минимумом динамики и без задела на большое развитие в дальнейшем, то использование MVC мне кажется просто излишним.

Comment: Все именно так, сейчас простая демка, и если все хорошо быстрое расширение проекта. В общем спасибо, за понятный ответ. Будет больше рейтинга, плюсану)